# Summernote insertImage trigger onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

[onImageUpload Example](https://github.com/HackerWins/summernote/issues/72)

I have a script using summernote as a wysiwyg editor, and am using the example from the link about to handle image uploads. However, the editor.insertImage function doesn't trigger the summernote onChange event (which is what I'm using to save the content of the editor). Does anyone know how I can call the summernote onChange function from within the onImageUpload callback?

Comment: Instead of triggering the onChange event, I instead modified the plugin to accept a callback function in the editor.insertImage function. This solved my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was summernote's bug. Now I fixed it. Thanks you for reporting.

- Release Note: https://github.com/HackerWins/summernote/releases/tag/v0.5.8
- Commit: http://goo.gl/35ln9F